# Toggle switch content not displayed in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, radgridview, toggleswitch

I'm using a custom style for my toggle switch. The style is applied and it works fine and it shows "ON" or "OFF". The problem is when I add the toggle switch to the `DataGrid`.

The `DataGrid` item source is binding to a model and the column `isActive` contains the toggle switch control. The toggle will take the green color if `isActive` is `true` or red color if is `false`, but it doesn't show the content text ( "ON" , "OFF").

**Style of the toggle Switch in Resources file:**

```
<Style x:Key="ActiveToggleSwitch" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">

        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="toggleSwitch">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="10"
        Background="#C2283B"
        Width="90" Height="25">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.6" Direction="0" Opacity="0.3" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse" Fill="#FFFFFFFF" Stretch="Uniform"
             Margin="2 2 2 1"
             Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.2"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="22" >
                            <Ellipse.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.3" Direction="260" />
                            </Ellipse.Effect>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Border>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="txtOff" Text="{Binding TextOFF}" Margin="0 0 40 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" FontSize="10" />
                    <TextBlock Opacity="0" x:Name="txtOn"  Text="{Binding TextON}" Margin="40 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold"  Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="10" />
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True" >
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>

                            <BeginStoryboard>

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="#34A543"
                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    To="60 2 2 1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"     />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"  />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <!--  some out fading  -->
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="#C2283B"
                                Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    To="2 2 2 1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1"       />
                                    <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                            From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:0:0.1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource IdealForegroundColorBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="Activetoogle" IsReadOnly="True"  HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource CustomGridViewHeaderCellStyle}" Header="{StaticResource ActivityTriggerSwitch}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding isActive}" Width="*">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Height ="Auto" >
                <ToggleButton  x:Name="isActive"  VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="False"  Style="{StaticResource ActiveToggleSwitch}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="auto" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" IsChecked="{Binding empisActive}" Content="{Binding ToogleContent}"  />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow(){
    InitializeComponent();
    TextOFF = (string)Application.Current.Resources["NotActive"];
    TextON = (string)Application.Current.Resources["IsActive"];
}
// ...
```

I'm trying to get the text displayed in the column of the toggle switch, how can I do that?

**Note :** This works if the toggle switch is not created inside the data template.

The toggle button should contain the text ("ON" or "OFF").

[image: DataGrid with toggle switches.]

Answer (score 0):

The `TextOFF` and `TextON` properties are defined in your `MainWindow`, not in the data context of the **current item** in the grid view column. Since your bindings are hard-wired to the current data context, this does not work, the properties are not defined there.

### Dirty Workaround

You could change the data context like below, which is a **really dirty workaround** and **I do not recommend it**. It sets the data context to the `MainWindow`, so the `ToggleButton` works and exploits the `StackPanel` data context to bind items.

```
<ToggleButton  x:Name="isActive"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               IsEnabled="False"
               Style="{StaticResource ActiveToggleSwitch}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
               Width="auto"
               FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
               DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourProject:MainWindow}}}"
               IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.empisActive, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}"
               Content="{Binding DataContext.ToogleContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}" />
```

### Solutions with Dependency Properties

You should not use a binding on a property path directly in a control template. This binding will always rely on the exact property names `TextOFF` and `TextON` and the current data context, instead use one of these options:

- Create a custom control derived from `ToggleButton` and add dependency properties for the *On* and *Off* texts.
- Create custom attached properties to for the *On* and *Off* texts.

In both cases, you can bind the texts from outside. I prefer the first option, because your switch button might have other properties that it could expose which fit its special behavior or appearance.

```
public class SwitchButton : ToggleButton
{
   static SwitchButton()
   {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SwitchButton),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SwitchButton)));
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty OffTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(OffText), typeof(string), typeof(SwitchButton));

   public static readonly DependencyProperty OnTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(OnText), typeof(string), typeof(SwitchButton));

   public string OffText
   {
      get => (string)GetValue(OffTextProperty);
      set => SetValue(OffTextProperty, value);
   }

   public string OnText
   {
      get => (string)GetValue(OnTextProperty);
      set => SetValue(OnTextProperty, value);
   }
}
```

Now, remove the `x:Key` from your template and change the types to `SwitchButton`. Without the key, the style will be implicit and applied to all `SwitchButton` controls in scope automatically. Please also notice that the bindings are now `TemplateBinding`s that bind to the dependency properties of the `SwitchButton`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type YourProject:SwitchButton}">
   <Setter Property="IsChecked"
           Value="False" />
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
           Value="Left" />
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
           Value="Center" />
   <Setter Property="Template">

      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type YourProject:SwitchButton}">
            <Grid x:Name="toggleSwitch">
               <Border x:Name="Border"
                       CornerRadius="10"
                       Background="#C2283B"
                       Width="90"
                       Height="25">
                  <Border.Effect>
                     <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0.6"
                                       Direction="0"
                                       Opacity="0.3" />
                  </Border.Effect>
                  <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse"
                           Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           Margin="2 2 2 1"
                           Stroke="Gray"
                           StrokeThickness="0.2"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           Width="22">
                     <Ellipse.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"
                                          ShadowDepth="1"
                                          Opacity="0.3"
                                          Direction="260" />
                     </Ellipse.Effect>
                  </Ellipse>
               </Border>

               <TextBlock x:Name="txtOff"
                          Text="{TemplateBinding OffText}"
                          Margin="0 0 40 0"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          FontWeight="DemiBold"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                          Foreground="White"
                          FontSize="10" />
               <TextBlock Opacity="0"
                          x:Name="txtOn"
                          Text="{TemplateBinding OnText}"
                          Margin="40 0 0 0"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          FontWeight="DemiBold"
                          Foreground="White"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          FontSize="10" />
            </Grid>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked"
                        Value="True">
                  <Trigger.EnterActions>

                     <BeginStoryboard>

                        <Storyboard>
                           <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                           To="#34A543"
                                           Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                           <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                               To="60 2 2 1"
                                               Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="1.0"
                                            To="0.0"
                                            Duration="0:0:0:0.1" />
                           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="0.0"
                                            To="1.0"
                                            Duration="0:0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                     </BeginStoryboard>
                  </Trigger.EnterActions>
                  <!--  some out fading  -->
                  <Trigger.ExitActions>
                     <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                           <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                           To="#C2283B"
                                           Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                           <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                               To="2 2 2 1"
                                               Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txtOff"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="0"
                                            To="1.0"
                                            Duration="0:0:0:0.1" />
                           <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txtOn"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="1.0"
                                            To="0.0"
                                            Duration="0:0:0:0.1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                     </BeginStoryboard>
                  </Trigger.ExitActions>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground"
                          Value="{DynamicResource IdealForegroundColorBrush}" />
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                        Value="False">
               </Trigger>

               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="False">
                  <Setter Property="Foreground"
                          Value="{DynamicResource GrayBrush7}" />
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
           Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

This allows you to bind the *Off* and *On* texts from outside. In your case, you would need to use a `RelativeSource` binding to access the `TextOFF` and `TextON` properties in your `MainWindow`.

```
<YourProject:SwitchButton  x:Name="isActive"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           IsEnabled="False"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Width="auto"
                           FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
                           IsChecked="{Binding empisActive}"
                           Content="{Binding ToogleContent}"
                           OffText="{Binding TextOFF, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourProject:MainWindow}}}"
                           OnText="{Binding TextON, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourProject:MainWindow}}}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I'm really not familiar with ViewModel and Dependency property, for that reason I'm searching for a simple solution.

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 Since your bindings are hard-wired, the workaround, although I do not recommend it, is probably as simple as it gets.

Comment: As you said in the answer, you have written two methods that I can use could you please separte them to understand exactly the first method ( I think that the first code fragment is about the first option or first method ) ??

Comment: The first option not working for me, this is not a window, it is Page

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 I have separated both solutions. In your question, you have a `MainWindow` so I guessed it must be a window. In case you use a `Page`, use `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"`.

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 I think you should update your question to provide more context where `TextOFF` and `TextON` are defined, as well as where your data grid is defined. Otherwise there is no way of knowing why it does not work.

Comment: I have added the complete style of the toggle switch

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 Yes, the style, but not the `MainWindow` code or markup that shows how the properties are defined and where they are actually used and that seems to be the issue here, that the structure is different than the question suggests.

Comment: What do you mean exactly , I have posted the code c# ( MainWindow.xaml.cs ) that I set the content of the TextON and TextOFF , and for the xaml I have posted the code of the column that contains the data template of the toggle button

Answer (score 0):

You can use string resource directly in xaml, using ViewModel in your case is unnecessary step

```
xmlns:stringResources="clr-namespace:YourApp.Properties"

<TextBlock x:Name="txtOff" Text="{x:Static stringResources:Resources.NotActive}" Margin="0 0 40 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="DemiBold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" FontSize="10" />
```

Comment: Could you give me more details?

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 What exactly is not clear? If you use Resource in xaml you don't need to care which ViewModel use for binding.

Comment: I tested your code and this does not work for me, I'm using a file called window for styles ( the code for the style of the toggle switch is inside it )